# strapi-girdsome starter issues

Tags: strapi, gridsome

When following official strapi-gridsome tutorial, trying to create new pages from ID numbers

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
npm: '6.14.9',
node: '14.14.0',
strapi '3.5.0'
```

**Expected result:**

http://localhost:8080/categories/1
should show data from API but instead shows 404 page

**Actual result:**

When running `gridsome develop`...

```
ERROR Failed to compile with 1 errors
This dependency was not found:
..\my-gridsome-site\src\templates\Category.vue in ./src/.temp/routes.js
```

*gridsome.server.js*

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.loadSource(({ addCollection }) => {
    // Use the Data Store API here: https://gridsome.org/docs/data-store-api/
  })

  api.createPages(async ({ graphql, createPage }) => {
    const { data } = await graphql(`
      {
        allStrapiCategory {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `);

    const categories = data.allStrapiCategory.edges;

    categories.forEach(category => {
      createPage({
        path: `/categories/${category.node.id}`,
        component: './src/templates/Category.vue',
        context: {
          id: category.node.id,
        },
      });
    });
  });
};
```

*src\templates\category.vue*

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    <div>
      <h1>{{ $page.category.name }}</h1>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="restaurant in $page.category.restaurants">{{ restaurant.name }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </Layout>
</template>

<page-query>
  query Category($id: ID!) {
      category: strapiCategory(id: $id) {
        name
        restaurants {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
</page-query>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.
I was running `yarn develop` and hot-reload was working for general playing with data, layout etc. But when editing `gridsome.server.js` these changes aren't reflected.
This is solved by re-starting the server. And now you'll have your dynamic pages.